# Change the sequence of adjacent pairs in a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector 'a'

```
a <- c(2, 1.2, 1.2, 2, 2, 2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 2, 1.2, 2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2)
```

I need to create a new vector 'b' in which, wherever the number 1.2 is repeated as adjacent pairs should be present only once. The new vector 'b' should be

```
b <- c(2, 1.2, 2, 2, 2, 1.2, 1.2, 2, 1.2, 2, 1.2, 1.2)
```

Any suggestions using ifelse() or while().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `rle` in combination with `ifelse` and `ceiling` :

```r
a <- c(2, 1.2, 1.2, 2, 2, 2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 2, 1.2, 2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2)

b <- with(rle(a), 
          rep(values, ifelse(values == 1.2, ceiling(lengths / 2), lengths)))

b
#>  [1] 2.0 1.2 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.2 1.2 2.0 1.2 2.0 1.2 1.2
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was wondering whether if it is possible to obtain the answer using only ifelse() without the rle() combination.

Comment: ifelse will always return a vector the same length its inputs.